# Avoiding Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path With Regex

Tags: java, spring

I have to similar controllers ONe get by Id and the other get By name 
both using PathVariables I read an article where it explained and how to resolve by using regex but it seems not to work properly

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/trucks/{truckId:[0-9]+}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public final TruckDto getTruckId(@PathVariable(value = "truckId")
                                         final String truckId) {

        LOGGER.debug("test: truckId({})", truckId);
        Truck truck = truckService.getTruckById(Integer.parseInt(truckId));
        return mappingService.map(truck, TruckDto.class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Truck with an average.
     */
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value = "/trucks/{truckCode:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}")
    public final TruckWithAvgPetrolDto getTruckByTruckCode(@PathVariable(value = "truckCode")
                                                     final String truckCode) {

        LOGGER.debug("test: getTruckByTruckCode({})", truckCode);

        TruckWithAvgDto truck = truckService.getTruckByTruckCode(truckCode);

        return mappingService.map(truck, TruckWithAvgPetrolDto.class);
    }
```

WIthout putting regex both of fail my test but after putting regex the method getTruckByTruckCode that accepts numbers and letters pass but get by truckId still gives the error ambigous handler method , Am i missing something or why isnt it working

Comment: Obviously a number matches both regular expressions so getTruckId mapping *is* ambiguous.

Comment: ohh But I thought since it can accept both numbers and letters ,it should be different from the other , But what is the way forward?

Comment: Presumably, a truck code cannot be pure digits, because otherwise how would you know if a sequence of digits is an `id` or a `code`. So the code regex must fail to match a pure-digit value, e.g. `{truckCode:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*}`, i.e. optional leading digits, non-digit, then any set of valid characters. --- Now, if a code *can* be pure digits, then you need to change the path, e.g. `/trucks/5` would be by `id`, but `/trucks/code/5` would be by `code`.

Comment: my truckCode usually starts from two letters BY3432 for example

Comment: However, you're violating REST principles. A truck is a resource, with a single unique resource URL: `/trucks/{id}`. To lookup a truck by other values is a *query*, so `/trucks/?code={code}` would be a more appropriate URL for that.

Comment: *"Usually"*? That's not a rule. A rule must cover all possible values.

Comment: yes but truckCode is a unique value in my database also ? is it still not appropriate to use a seperate method for get by truckCode?

Comment: This is because my get by id just gets truck details but my get by truckCode is performing a join and get truck info plus and averagevalue from a second table

Comment: @Andreas what do you think

Comment: As you said yourself, get by id is just gets truck details, i.e. the truck **resource** itself, while get by truckCode returns a "report" for the result of a query. Just because the query only return one truck object, doesn't mean it's not a query.

Comment: so my url should be something like /trucks/{id}/code   where code is optional param ? @Andreas

Comment: I gave two example, neither of them was that. But hey, it's your code. You can do whatever you want.

Comment: yes i did not get your example , i want to do it the right way , can you please explain better , i want to follow the right principle, Thank you @Andreas

Comment: I said you could try `/trucks/code/BY3432` or better yet `/trucks/?code=BY3432`. What don't you understand about that?

Comment: ok thank you i should make code just an optional param,